# Convert date and time string to valid date

Tags: momentjs

I have the following string.

`"2021-07-01 10:00"`

How can I convert this into a valid date with moment.js?

I tried the below, it says invalid date.

```
moment("2021-07-01 10:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try some something like this:

```js
var res = moment("2021-07-01 10:00", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm").format(
  "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm"
);
console.log(res);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly the same as mine :)

Comment: what do you want as O/P?

Answer (score 0):

I realised, nothing is wrong with this script. I used a variable instead of the string and I realised that was an object: `{_text: "2021-07-01 10:00"}`